# Aligning text vertically using display table-cell

Tags: html, css

I'm having a little bit of a problem aligning text vertically. I've tried several ways and it either aligns text vertically but then stacks the list items vertically or if I use display: inline-block the text aligns to the top. Not sure what I'm missing. Any help is truly appreciated. Thanks.

https://jsfiddle.net/u4kLvjox/

html code

```
<ul class="maptext">
  <a class="map-active" href="right_1.html"><li>FIRST ITEM</li></a>
  <a href="right_2.html"><li>SECOND LIST<br> ITEM</li></a>
  <a href="right_3.html"><li>THIRD LINE ITEM</li></a>
</ul>
```

css code

```
ul.maptext {
    color: #743237;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
}

ul.maptext li {
    background-color: #b0b659;
    color: #743237;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 33.3333%;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.maptext a {
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #743237;
}

ul.maptext li:hover {
    background-color: #743237;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Your markup is inverted, the `li` should wrap the `a` tag, not the other way around.

Comment: I need to make the li clickable and not just the text.

Comment: @BrettDeWoody I just added a fiddle. I need to make the text align vertically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the commenter pointed out, you need to put the `<a>` tags inside the `<li>` tags. That wills solve part of the problem.

To make the entire block clickable, give your `<a>` element a `display: block;` with a `height: 100%`.

Here's a [full demo](http://jsfiddle.net/brettdewoody/3a0L6LvL/).

Answer (score 1):

You can align text vertically by adding a `:before` style as below.

```css
ul.maptext {
color: #743237;
line-height: 22px;
font-size: 11px;
text-align:center;
font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
/* display: inline-block; */
margin: 0;
}

ul.maptext li {
background-color: #b0b659;
color: #743237;
display: inline-block;
width: 33.3333%;
height: 48px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
margin: 0 -2px;
}

ul.maptext a {
line-height: 15px;
color: #743237;
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
}
ul.maptext a:before {
content: "";
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: middle;
width: 1px;
height: 100%;
}
ul.maptext li:hover {
background-color: #743237;
color: #fff;
}

#mapview {
  width: 700px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="mapview">
<ul class="maptext">
  <li><a class="map-active" href="right_1.html">FIRST ITEM</a></li>
  <li><a href="right_2.html">SECOND LIST ITEM</a></li>
  <li><a href="right_3.html">THIRD LINE ITEM</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the results you want requires less markup:

```css
.maptext {
    display: table; 
    table-layout: fixed;
    height: 48px;
  
    color: #743237;
    line-height: 22px;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
}

.maptext a {
    display: table-cell; 
    width: 33.3333%;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;

    background-color: #b0b659;
    line-height: 15px;
    color: #743237;
}

.maptext a:hover {
  background-color: #743237;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="maptext" role="menu">
      <a class="map-active" href="right_1.html" role="menuitem">FIRST ITEM</a>
      <a href="right_2.html" role="menuitem">SECOND LIST<br> ITEM</a>
      <a href="right_3.html" role="menuitem">THIRD LINE ITEM</a>
</div>
```

The only downside is that screenreaders without ARIA support lose the list structure, although the links are still accessible.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try with

```
display:table-cell;
```

and on parent element:

```
display:table;
```

Here is an example:
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/02ays6h3/1/)

```css
ul.maptext {
    color: #743237;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: table;
    margin: 0;
    width:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding:0;
}

ul.maptext a {
    background-color: #b0b659;
    color: #743237;
    display: table-cell;
    width: 33.333%;
    height: 48px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

ul.maptext a:hover {
    background-color: #743237;
    color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul class="maptext">
  <a class="map-active" href="right_1.html"><li>FIRST ITEM</li></a>
  <a href="right_2.html"><li>SECOND LIST<br/> ITEM</li></a>
  <a href="right_3.html"><li>THIRD LINE ITEM</li></a>
</ul>
```